# Umpermitted parameter in rails devise, even though params .permit(ted)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have rails (6.0.2.2) project with devise (4.7.1), with two types of accounts: the teachers and the students. The student can to sign up successfully, but there is problem with the teacher for some reason. When I try to make a test account, I get

```
Unpermitted parameter: :email
```

error message and my info is not saved in the database.

Migration:

```
class DeviseCreateTeachers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
def change
create_table :teachers do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  t.string :username
  t.string :name
  t.string :neighborhood
  t.integer :pet_skin
  t.integer :pet_eyes
  t.integer :pet_face
  t.integer :pet_accessories


  ## Trackable
  # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  t.string   :confirmation_token
  t.datetime :confirmed_at
  t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  t.datetime :locked_at


  t.timestamps null: false
end

add_index :teachers, :email,                unique: true
add_index :teachers, :reset_password_token, unique: true
# add_index :teachers, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
# add_index :teachers, :unlock_token,         unique: true
end
end
```

my teacher_controller.rb:

```
class TeacherController < ApplicationController

private

def sign_up_params
  params.require(:teacher).permit(:email, :username, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :neighborhood, :pet_skin, :pet_eyes, :pet_face)
end

def account_update_params
  params.require(:teacher).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
end

end
```

I'm using the default generated teachers/registration/new.html.erb so I think its no problem here.

I DID add a line to config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.authentication_keys = [:username]
```

to change default log in from email to username, but I don't think this is issue because again students can create the account.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

@Tijana I don't know if you have already checked this.
link. If not, it might help
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#strong-parameters